# {body} does not output <p> tags

Tags: html

I am having trouble figuring out how to get my paragraphs to wrap in < p >< /p >

Need to implement **p** tags inside < content > element:
http://www.free-times.com/arts/rss_arts

Using EE v2.7.2

Answer (score 0):

Whereabouts is the content coming from? If it's in a WYSIWYG field, check the source to see if it includes `<p>` tags within the markup. If it does these should be output to your template.

The alternative might be to place a `<p>` tag in your template with the correct output block inside, e.g.
`<p>{body}</p>`

Comment: { body } does not output p tags from the WYSIWYG field, only < /br > tags

Comment: When I have a story opened, I notice there is a "Formatting:" option that is defaulting to  "Auto < /br >" How do I change this?

Comment: @lbjw is it possible for you to upload a screenshot? I think that's an option you can change in a drop-down in the Admin panel.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for your help. I figured out where to change the text formatting setting:  Admin > Channel Admin > Channel Fields > Body 

This has fixed the original issue. However, now I am realizing that the exp:xml_encode tag that wraps around the body tag is stripping out `<p></p>` tags. Do you have advice as to how to allow `<p>` tags inside the exp:xml_encode tag?

<code>`{exp:xml_encode}`{body}`{exp:xml_encode}`</code>

Comment: disregard -- realized I need to swap out the xml_encode tag for      <![CDATA[{body}]]>